# boost mapped_file_sink throw exception

Tags: c++, boost

I don't know why it throw exception when I create mapped_file_sink object.

Exception:

```
terminate called after throwing an instance of 
'boost::exception_detail::clone_impl<boost::exception_detail::error_info_injector<std::exception> >'
```

```
int main(int argc,char *argv[])
{
        boost::iostreams::mapped_file_sink sink(argv[1]);
        char temp[] ="AAAA";
        memcpy(sink.data(), temp, sizeof(temp));
        sink.close();
        return 1;
}
```

Comment: Have you tried catching the exception and printing out `what()`?

Comment: what():  N5boost16exception_detail10clone_implINS0_19error_info_injectorISt9exceptionEEEE

Comment: Michael, have you figured out what the problem is ? I'm having exact issue.

Comment: No I still have no idea.

Answer (score 0):

Most likely file `AAAA` doesn't exist. In order to create the file you need to open memory-mapped file using `boost::iostreams::mapped_file_params` variable whose `new_file_size` field would be set to desirable size of file.

Comment: argv[1] is the file not AAAA. AAAA is the content which is to write to the file

Comment: Ah you're right. I'm sorry. I had same exception today and in my case it was related to zero in `length` field of `mapped_file_params`.

Comment: so you do not have exception after setting length field to a correct value with the same code above?

Comment: @MichaelD, that's right. Setting it to default -1 fixed the error.

Answer (score 0):

With boost 1.53 in a 64 bit Linux virtual machine, I too encountered the exception reported above.

I eventually tracked it down to a permission problem.  When I ran my test from a virtual box share folder I could create the and size file, but I would get the mystery exception when BOOST_IOSTREAMS_FD_MMAP failed calling cleanup_and_throw("failed mapping file").

Somewhere along the way in the throw enable_current_exception(enable_error_info(e)); call the "failed mapping file: invalid argument" message is lost.

If the same code were run from my home folder the api works as expected.

So the essence of my problem came down to permissions.  I hope this helps anyone else who encounters this.

drwxrwx--- root vboxsf

vs

drwxr-xr-x user user